# how to remove value of a CSS attribute for a UL tag using inline style

Tags: html, css, inline

I have a scenario where I want to remove a CSS property for a UL tag using inline style sheet.

```
ul, ol {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

I want to remove `padding` attribute using inline style. I tried to give `padding:-1` but it is not working. Currently `padding: 0` is received from a external CSS file which I cannot modify.

JQuery cannot be used in my case.

Please help.

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 2):

use `!important` property.
for example

```
padding: 2px !important;
```

Comment: I tried this `<ul style="padding:-1 !important; list-style-type:disc;">` still it is taking `padding:0` which it is receiving from external file

Comment: here, if I use firebug and remove `padding:0` property, it works. But I am not getting how to make it using inline style

Comment: try 
`ul, ol{
position:absolute;
top:-1px;
left:-1px;
}
`

Comment: how will  `position:absolute` can set right padding issue?

Comment: you cant give negative values for padding... by setting left or top you can move elements to negative position

Answer (score 0):

Negative values are not allowed. You can not give -1 padding.

Check below example. You can see in developer tool that it will remove negative padding. As it is not allowed.

```css
ul, ol {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul style="padding:-1 !important; list-style-type:disc;">
<ol>
test
</ol>
</ul>
```

But if you give positive value. It will override the previous with inline css.

```css
ul, ol {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul style="padding:10px; list-style-type:disc;">
<ol>
test
</ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, I agree. positive values will override the previous value. But in my case, I want to remove a property completely.

Comment: @ManojKumar `padding:0` and `margin:0` means it's remove padding and margin.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such thing as negative padding. You could use negative margin though, which proves to be very useful in certain cases. To remove the padding property you could use `important!` and set padding=none using inline styling as

```
<li style="padding:none !important"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [initial keyword](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#initial) to set a CSS value to its initial state e.g.

```
ul, ol {
 margin: initial;
 padding: initial;
}
```

or the [unset keyword](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#inherit-initial) to unset it e.g.

```
ul, ol {
 margin: unset;
 padding: unset;
}
```

which will set an inherited property to inherit and a reset property to unset.